Rank Math Seo register custom xml url
Using Rank Math SEO plugin generates below xml file.
https://yoursitename.com/sitemap_index.xml
https://yoursitename.com/page-sitemap.xml
I want to register new sitemap url for custom data generated by me like below.
https://yoursitename.com/objects.xml
In this i write new custom urls of Property and objects

If the question is how to accomplish that using the Rank Math plugin, you should inquire in the plugin's support channels or associated communities. If you're trying to implement that independently of Rank Math, you might consider removing the reference from the question, and including any efforts or research you have made thus far.
